# Can you simplify $\lfloor x\rfloor-\lfloor y\rfloor$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there any way to simplify $\lfloor x\rfloor-\lfloor y\rfloor$, preferably such that the result is in the form of $\lfloor f(x, y)\rfloor$ for some function $f$?

I attempted to replace $\lfloor x\rfloor$ with $x - (x\;\text{mod}\;1)$ and the same with $y$ to get $(x - y) - ((x\;\text{mod}\;1)-(y\;\text{mod}\;1))$, but I couldn't get past this.

Comment: You can write x mod 1 - y mod 1 as x-y mod 1, but other than that, I see no other way to write this.

Comment: It is $\lfloor f(x,y) \rfloor$ where $f(x,y) = \lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor y \rfloor$.  But that's hardly a simplification.

Comment: simplified in what sense? Like what do you wanna do with it? I might have a couple of ideas to change the look of it. They could be simplifications depending on your use

Comment: @JonathanHebert wouldn't that reduce to $\lfloor x\rfloor-\lfloor y\rfloor=\lfloor x-y\rfloor$? I don't think that's true.

Comment: @Euler_Salter In the sense that the $x$ and $y$ are no longer separated in their floor functions, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Comment: try with stuff like gauss stuff $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x+y}$ or whatever and try to make it seems like it

Comment: Try using an expression using the average of x, y.

Comment: @Euler_Salter that's just $x-y$...

Comment: exactly.... that's the whole point

Comment: that's the Gauss technique, to rewrite simple things in terms of nice algebraic expressions (multiplications and fractions) so that you can then use other properties to make it look even nicer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most reasonable conceptions of "nice," there isn't a nice function $f$ that satisfies your criterion. Generally, the form you have is considered the simplest.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks for the response!